# Scala reflection for logging purposes

Tags: scala

Is it possible in Scala, to get the name of the member/function containing your code? e.g. in order to accomplish code like

```
def someFunc() {
  Log(s"error $x occurred in function ${SomeScalaAPI.enclosingFunction}")
}
```

that would produce a string:

"error X occurred in function someFunc"

without resorting to [creating and catching exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15493556/scala-logging-function-name)? I would like to assume since exceptions know where they happen, this information might be available through some Scala or Java reflection api.. or, via a clever compile time macro?

Thanks!

Comment: If you use e.g. log4j, there is a variety of settings you can use to set up your logging, including method name: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html

Comment: Thanks but I always prefer my own logging over the staple loggers with all their quirks (e.g. on the link you mentioned "synchronization and other issues") and arbitrary logging levels. I wonder what api log4j uses for accomplishing it.. that can help if Scala has nothing else..

Answer (score 7):

Time for some macro magic:

```
import language.experimental.macros

import reflect.macros.blackbox.Context

case class Location(filename: String, line: Int, column: Int, enclosingMethod : Option[String])

object PositionMacro {
  def currentLocation: Location = macro impl

  def impl(c: Context): c.Expr[Location] = {
    import c.universe._
    val pos = c.macroApplication.pos
    val owner = c.internal.enclosingOwner //Old, deprecated way: c.enclosingMethod.symbol
    val enclosingMethod = Some(owner).filter(_.isMethod).map(_.fullName)
    c.Expr(q"Location(${pos.source.path}, ${pos.line}, ${pos.column}, ${enclosingMethod})")
  }
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
def test(): Unit = {
  println(s"Called from ${PositionMacro.currentLocation}")
}

test()
// Called from Location(C:\Users\sschwets\AppData\Local\Temp\scratchPad.sc9.tmp,9,41,Some(A$A22.A$A22.test))
```

I added the following to my `build.sbt` file:

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.4"

libraryDependencies +=
  "org.scala-lang" % "scala-reflect" % scalaVersion.value % "provided"
```

**Attention:** This is my very first macro with the Scala 2.11 interface and quasi quotes. It works fine for me, but might format your hard disc, empty your bank account, spoil your children, anger your cat or run away with your wife / husband / whatever. So please be careful!

Comment: Upvoted for your *Attention* grabber. Ok .. the code is also nice.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with java:

```
java.lang.Thread.currentThread.getStackTrace()(1).getMethodName
```

Example:

```
scala> def aa = {println(java.lang.Thread.currentThread.getStackTrace()(1).getMethodName)}
aa: Unit

scala> aa
aa
```

But it won't work for functions - only for methods:

```
scala> val zz = aa _
zz: () => Unit = <function0>

scala> zz()
aa

scala> val zzz = () => println(java.lang.Thread.currentThread.getStackTrace()(1).getMethodName)
zzz: () => Unit = <function0>

scala> zzz()
apply$mcV$sp
```

If you're looking for some compile-time macro, there is a simmilar solution - https://github.com/dk14/println-tracer; example of usage:

```
@trace class MyF {
  def call(param: Int): Int = if (param == 0) param else call(param - 1)
  def call2(param2: Int) = param2
  def call3(param2: Int) = ???
}

(new MyF).call(2)
(new MyF).call2(666)
Try{(new MyF).call3(666)}
```

Results:

```
 call(param = 2)
  call(param = 1)
   call(param = 0)
   call = 0
  call = 0
 call = 0
 call2(param2 = 666)
 call2 = 666
 call3(param2 = 666)
 call3 = scala.NotImplementedError: an implementation is missing
```

It uses `println` instead of logger (which is fixable) and requires macro-paradise library. All parameters/errors are printed automatically, which may be not what you want, but you can use it as a template if there is no logging-ready library around.

Comment: stupid question - wouldn't this just capture the method in which aa is defined? it would be nice to have a utility function that will grab the name of the method it is _called in_.

Comment: stupid answer :) - `java.lang.Thread.currentThread.getStackTrace()(2).getMethodName` (2 instead of 1 here)

Comment: I think it will capture any anonymous function enclosing the call to aa though, rather than the method enclosing them both, as per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15493556/scala-logging-function-name. I will look into macros..

Comment: yes it will, you can filter them by using `$` (as they named like apply$mcV$sp), not the best way, but didn't find any analog in `scala.mirror`

Comment: actually i've written simmilar macro - [readme](https://github.com/dk14/println-tracer/tree/master), [macro](https://github.com/dk14/println-tracer/blob/master/macro/src/main/scala/Generator.scala), [test](https://github.com/dk14/println-tracer/blob/master/test/src/main/scala/Test.scala). It prints every call of function, which class is marked with @trace annotation. It's not exactly what you want but close.

Comment: very cute :) quite a quick bag of code, I take my hat off :)